# Difference between ++ and += 1 at the REPL with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

```
counter  = 1;
time = 60;

while (counter < time) {
    console.log(counter);
    counter += 1;
}
```

Why is the value of the code in REPL above 1 to 60

While the output of the code in REPL below is 1 to 59:

```
counter  = 1;
time = 60;

while (counter < time) {
    console.log(counter);
    counter++;
}
```

I tested both of the codes in the REPL.

Comment: Are you sure you copy pasted the code 100% the same?

Comment: Yes, i'm positive.

Comment: There is no difference to my knowledge, and in this code example it's even irrelevant, since what you say would mean that the condition of the while loop would be exceeded in the first code snippet, which is not plausible.

Comment: [They are the same](https://jsfiddle.net/t3kxufxy/), must be the way you're displaying it.

Comment: I get the same results (1 - 59) from that fiddle :)

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, I can provide screenshots of both the codes at my terminal.

Comment: The downvotes are not warranted, but you have indeed posted two pieces of code that will generate exactly the same result.  You have made a mistake that does not appear in the code you have posted.

Comment: No he hasn't, jesus why are people so bitchy on SO today o_O

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because `node` REPL by default print out the result of the last command.

In your first case, the last command is `counter++`, which increase counter to 60 and returns 59

In the second case, the last command is `count += 1`, which increase counter to 60 and returns 60

It is more clear if you run it inside Chrome developer console

[image]

In the `node` REPL case, you can still see the difference that the last number have different color, indicated it is the value of last evaluation instead of output of `console.log`

[image]

Comment: This is, I think, the correct and complete explanation. That could be demonstrated clearly by changing the `console.log()` calls in both examples to include something other than just the counter value in the output. That way, the output from the explicit `console.log()` calls could be distinguished from the simple console output of the last evaluated expression.

Comment: In both of those, the console.log from the code returns 1, and then 2.  The only difference, the evaluated value of the last line, is not actually part of the code given.

Answer (score 4):

In both cases your loop only outputs `1` through `59`, however, the node REPL also outputs the result of the last evaluated expression.

In the first case the last evaluated expression was `(counter += 1)` which evaluates to the new value of counter (60), while in the second case the last evaluated expression was `(counter++)` which evaluates to the value of counter before the increment (59). If you looked carefully you would have seen that `59` appeared in the output twice in the second version (printed once by `console.log` and once by the REPL.

If you're not convinced, try this one out:

```
counter  = 1;
time = 60;

while (counter < time) {
    console.log(counter);
    counter += 1;
    'Hello!';
}
```

Comment: This was an awesome way to demonstrate what's going on, thanks Paul :)

Answer (score 1):

The two pieces of code behave exactly the same.  `a++;` as a statement will have exactly the same effect as `a += 1;`

If you are having problems, they stem from outside of the example code you've shown us.

The difference between `a++` and `a += 1` would only be in the returned value, which you are *not* using in your example code.  The returned value of `a++` is the value of `a` before incrementing it.  The returned value of `a += 1` is the value of `a` *after* incrementing it.  This difference, however, will not manifest itself in your code because you are not asking for its return value.

You have made a mistake in the way you have simplified your code for your example.  The two pieces of code in your example will behave the same.

Comment: If you are getting a different behaviour from these two pieces of code, then you are not actually just running those two pieces of code.  You are likely running it in an interactive console which is also outputting the return value of the last line of code evaluated.  It's important to distinguish that from output that is actually generated by the code itself.  Look at the start of Brian Chen's answer.  The output from the console.log() calls are equal in both cases, the interactive console is just adding its own evaluation of the last line.  This won't be output in production.

Comment: Brian's answer points out that this is because node's interactive console (an REPL) outputs the return value of the last expression.  I approve of that explanation but still point out that a strict answer to this question is, those two pieces of code will behave exactly the same, what we are seeing here is probably not the problem the OP was having in their un-simplified code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that "+=1" and "++" is worked same in your code.

However, in fact, there is a little difference.

For instance, in the following code.

```
a = 1
b = a+=1 
console.log(a,b)

2 2

a = 1
b = a++
console.log(a,b)

2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The last command executed on your terminal will be print by default, so if you console.log after assigning the number.. You will get the expected result.

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript, counter++ will return the value before incrementing. It will, however, still increment the counter just like +=1 will.

So your while loop will break out at the exact same point, which is why all the white text is the same - all the console.logs() are printing the same stuff. It is after the console.log loop however, Node is doing something special. It's printing in yellow the last returned value from the loop, which is for the +=1 code is 60, but the ++ code is 59.

FWIW, this was a good question and the downvoters shame stackoverflow.

Comment: The `console.log()` output from both posted code samples is identical.

Comment: Right, irrelevant though, since ++ returns the value before the increment.